# Joining 2 tables on similar strings

Tags: pandas, string, postgresql, join, sql-like

To brief you, I am trying to find the duplicates in a dataset.

What I am trying to do is something similar to this
'''

```
With no1 as (
Select 'Hi I am sam'::text s
), no2 as (
Select 'Hi, I am'::text s
) Select l.S,f.S
from no1 f 
join no2 l
on ('%'+f.s+'%') ILike ('%'+l.s+'%') OR ('%'+l.s+'%') ILike ('%'+f.s+'%')
```

'''

I want the on statement to include a clause that will join these two columns since they have similar strings. I tried using pg_trgm and similarity functions, but it seems it has to be done at the back end.

if this isn't doable, could you let me know how can I join these tables based on that Condition using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
on f.s ilike '%' || l.s || '%' or l.s ilike '%' ||  f.s || '%'
```

Rationale:

- `ilike` recognizes wildcards it its *right* operand; in the left operand, `'%'` is just a litteral percent sign, that prevents the match
- the string concatenation operator in Postgres is `||` (`+` is for numeric values)

Comment: Thank you GMB, What I am trying to do here is to identify possible duplicates on my dataset. In here since the strings has almost 8 characters similarity, then I would like to join the 2 statements. The on statements I used and you suggested works only if one is a substring of the other. Is there away to join based on similarity?